# C# How to save a function-call for in memory for later invoking

Tags: c#, types, delegates, xna

Is there any way in C# to save a function call for later invoking? For example, I want to be able to say:

```
public class MyFunctionCaller
{
    public static void SaveFunctionCallForLater(/* Some parameters*/)
    {
    // Save the Function Call in a variable or a list to be invoked after a set amount of time
   }
}

public class MyProgram
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Save a call to 'SpecialFunction' along with its parameters,
        // and maybe the object that's calling it (not applicable in
       // this example context, but important to my question)
        MyFunctionCaller.SaveFunctionCallForLater(/* Stuff */);
    }

    public void SpecialFunction(/* Stuff */)
    {
        // Does some cool stuff
    }
}
```

Let me give you some context: I'm creating a game in XNA and I want to create a DelayedFunctionCaller class, that any object can reference to hand complete function calls to, along with an amount of time to wait before it calls the function. I handle all of the time-waiting and triggering myself so that's not where I'm lost, I'm just not sure how or the correct way to package up the function to be passed to the DelayedFunctionCaller.

Here's the kicker: The DelayedFunctionCaller has to be able to run any function, no matter what object is sending it a function, what the function returns, or what parameters it takes**. I have over 100 classes in my game already, and the goal is to create an object that can save any function call from any one of them for later calling.

So from my own research, I've found the [`Type` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx), and I know that I can save the type of the object calling, the function name as a string (which is an acceptable sacrifice), then use [`GetMethod()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1.aspx) to save the method in a `MemberInfo`, then use [`MemberInfo`'s `Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) to call the function, even on a saved object, and with the parameters (as an array of `Objects`).

But this all seems very... hack-ish. I tried to look this up once and thought that [Generic Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx2bwtw7.aspx) was the way I wanted to go, but I got so lost in there that I gave up. Am I on the right track? Is this the only way to do this? What about Generic Delegates, or was I just out of my mind when I thought it would solve my problem?

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://pastebin.com/QKjDY1js), except that it will work for any method with any number of parameters, etc?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could save it as an Action, using a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

```
Action functionToCallLater = () => SpecialFunction(/* params */);
// later
functionToCallLater(); // calls SpecialFunction with its parameters
```

If the function returns something and you need its value, simply use the `Func<T>` type instead.

```
int MyMethod(int param) { return param + 1; }
(...)
Func<int> functionToCallLater = () => MyMethod(3);
(...)
int result = functionToCallLater(); // result == 4
```

Keep in mind that any variable you use within the lambda is captured itself, not its value; if its value changes, that'll be the value used when the function is called. See [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)'s blog for a deeper explanation.

Comment: ...Hm that's something I had no idea about. From everything I can look up atm, I keep reading that Actions can never have more than 2 variables, and I've never seen an example otherwise. Can I really call "Action savedAction = () => SpecialFunction(param1, param2, param3);"?

Also, I don't put any parameters in the "()" part of the lamdba call, do I?

Comment: The Action object itself doesn't need parameters; the parameters are saved within the lambda expression. That's what you want, right? You want the function call and its parameters saved inside something you can invoke later, and that's exactly what my example does. Read the page I linked to on MSDN, that should clear things out for you.

Comment: May I add, that if you want the exact current values of the variables to be sent to the method, you should copy them to tmp variables just before making the `Action`, and not change the tmp variables until the end of the scope.

Comment: Perfect, Dr_Asik, that's exactly what I wanted, just making sure =)

Comment: It's worth noting, especially for those of us working in XNA, that lambda expressions can generate a lot of garbage.  Each () => expression is equivalent to calling `new Action`, which of course places an object on the heap; further, lambda expressions with closed-over outer variables are promoted into a hidden class by the compiler, and the way that this class is instantiated and invoked means that additional garbage is generated every time you invoke the delegate.  Use them carefully if performance is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to lambda expressions, you can also use `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` methods. After, to invoke methods use foreach instruction. For example, this Unity engine code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class temp : MonoBehaviour {

    public IEnumerable myMethod1(string str){

        Debug.Log(str);
        yield return null;

    }

    public IEnumerable myMethod2(int number, string str){

        Debug.Log(number+str);
        yield return null;

    }

    System.Action CreateAction(params IEnumerable[] methodsArray){

        return () =>{

            IEnumerable[] methods = methodsArray;
            foreach(IEnumerable method in methods){ foreach(IEnumerable run in method); };

        };

    }


    void Start(){

        System.Action methodGroup = CreateAction(myMethod1("one"),myMethod2(1234,"two"));
        methodGroup();

    }
}
```